# Which java collection to use to compare 2 datasets?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have 2 datasets for 2 months with company name, Income and expense.
For each company, I need to provide the April Income and expense details and  percent change with  the previous month income and expense. scores.

Which java collection can i use to compare these 2 datasets?

Sample Datasets:

```
Month   Company_Name       Income   Expense
April        A             100         100
April        B             200         200
April        C             300         300
April        D             400         400
April        E             500         500


Month   Company_Name    Income     Expense
March        A              50       50
March        B              100     100
March        C              200     200
March        D              300     300
March        G              600     600
```

output should be like this

```
(Company Name: A, April Income: 100, April Expense: 100  percent Income change with previous month : 100)
(Company Name: B, April Income: 200, April Expense: 200  percent Income change with previous month : 100)
(Company Name: C, April Income: 300, April Expense: 300  percent Income change with previous month : 100)
(Company Name: D, April Income: 400, April Expense: 400  percent Income change with previous month : 100)
(Company Name: E, April Income: 500, April Expense: 500  percent Income change with previous month : N/A)
(Company Name: G, April Income: N/A, April Expense: N/A  percent Income change with previous month : N/A)
```

Here's what i unsucessfully tried?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> marchMap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> aprilMap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> revenueDetails=new ArrayList<Integer>();     

        // company A's march income and expense details
        revenueDetails.add(100); //income
        revenueDetails.add(100); //expense
        marchMap.put("A", revenueDetails); 

        // company B's march income and expense details
        revenueDetails.add(200); //income
        revenueDetails.add(200); //expense
        marchMap.put("B", revenueDetails); 

        // company A's april income and expense details
        revenueDetails.add(200); //income
        revenueDetails.add(200); //expense
        aprilMap.put("A", revenueDetails); 

        // company B's april income and expense details
        revenueDetails.add(300); //income
        revenueDetails.add(300); //expense
        aprilMap.put("B", revenueDetails); 

        // doesnt seem to be working. prints: A, 100, 100     B,100,100
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : aprilMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Company Name " + entry.getKey() + ": " + "   Income: " + entry.getValue().get(0) +  "   Expense: " + entry.getValue().get(1));
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have tried something. Please show us your code.

Comment: Isn't this same as your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376057/any-java-collection-to-compare-datasets

Comment: The answers to the previous incarnation of this question seemed to suggest a pretty clear path forward. Did you try that approach?

Comment: added my unsuccessful code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own class for the values you want to store in the Map.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, IncomeExpense) march = new HashMap<>();
        march.add(new IncomeExpense("March",100,100);
        ...
    }


    private static class IncomeExpense{
        private String month;
        private int income;
        private int expense;

        public IncomeExpense(String month, int income, int expense) {
            this.income = income;
            this.expense = expense;
        }


        public String toText() {
            return month + " Income: " + income + ", " + month + " Expense: " + expense;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not re-initializing the ArrayList. All entries are different ArrayList. So after adding each company entry for each month you have to create a new ArrayList as below,

```
      revenueDetails=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And the code must be like the below snippet,

```
    ArrayList<Integer> revenueDetails=new ArrayList<Integer>();     
    // company A's march income and expense details
    revenueDetails.add(100); //income
    revenueDetails.add(100); //expense
    marchMap.put("A", revenueDetails); 

    // company B's march income and expense details
    revenueDetails=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    revenueDetails.add(200); //income
    revenueDetails.add(200); //expense
    marchMap.put("B", revenueDetails);

 // company A's april income and expense details
    revenueDetails=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    revenueDetails.add(200); //income
    revenueDetails.add(200); //expense
    aprilMap.put("A", revenueDetails);
```